# Use of CSS property 'position' in ::after pseudoelement

Tags: css

I am new to HTML/CSS & was exploring different elements and properties. In the code below, I noticed that if I update the property 'position' to absolute or fixed, in the ::after pseudoelement, I am able to get the desired background color. However, changing the property to relative or static does not render the background color. Why is this happening; am I missing something here?

```css
p::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "XYZ";
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 10px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Sample text</p>
```

Comment: By default `pseudp-Element` are inline level element width and height properties have no effect on inline level elements, `position: absolute;` makes the element block level and therefore the width and height properties are effective

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you are using height and width for ? but try change these values to auto

```
  <style>
    p::after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "XYZ";
      background-color: yellow;
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
    }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

First make the parent element relative. Then only you can use position absolute on it's pseudo element.

```css
p {
  position:relative;
 }
 
 p::after{
       position: absolute;
      content: "XYZ";
      background-color: yellow;
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
  }
```

```html
<p>Sample Text</p>
```

```
  p { 
    position:relative;
   }

   p::after {
       position: absolute;
      content: "XYZ";enter code here
      background-color: yellow;
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use relative you can do this way

```
p{
position: relative
}
p::after{
  position: absolute
  content: "XYZ";
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 10px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

Instead of using absolute positioning you could use margins to position the p::after element.

**Absolute position:**
The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block.